# how to clear whole database in Rails seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to accomplish this? As for now I'm using:

```
Role.delete_all
User.delete_all
...
```

but how to clear habtm talbes? Like roles_users

### Updated Answer

I think ream88 response answers my question most precisely, but probably the bestidea is to follow coreyward suggestion to use separate rake tasks and leave seeds.rb only for seeding data.

This is updated answer from ream88 which doesn't delete `schema_migrations` table.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
  # MySQL
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table}") unless table == "schema_migrations"

  # SQLite
  # ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE FROM #{table}") unless table == "schema_migrations"
end
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I definitely agree with @coreyward's answer, but if you really want to clear all tables inside your `seeds.rb` file, this snippet will do the job:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
  next if table == 'schema_migrations'

  # MySQL and PostgreSQL
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table}")

  # SQLite
  # ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE FROM #{table}")
end
```

Comment: +1 for not resorting to running the Rake task from the Seed file.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I'll probably stick to coreyward's suggestion, but if I used your code, I'd probably exclude `schema_migration` table, since when deleted you have to apply all migrations anyway... Could get table name in that loop and exclude `schema_migration`

Comment: Simple `unless table == "schema_migrations"` is enough. I'll post updated answer in my question.

Comment: I prefer this answer.  There are some majorly annoying problems with trying to drop a PostgreSQL database (as I just discovered), so I'd rather make migration fixes with db:rollback/migrate (when necessary) and reseed with db:seed, with the seed file always truncating all tables first.  That's the most common/useful situation (you always want your db to start empty when seeding anyway) and separation of concerns, and avoids the dropping method.  THANKS!  (FYI-The MySQL line also works on PG)

Comment: in MySQL i had to wrap table name in quotations to prevent sql error "TRUNCATE `#{table}`"

Answer (score 49):

First of all, I don't think it's a good idea to mix concerns like this. The `seeds.rb` file is intended to seed the database with data, not reset it. There is already a rake task for resetting a database (`rake db:migrate:reset`) that just runs `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`. If you're wanting to seed a fresh database, you can just run `rake db:reset db:seed`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll stick probably to this convention. Just one thing surprises me - it seems that when I execute `db:reset` also all my seeds all automatically loaded. Is it possible or am I going crazy? :D

Comment: If you're running `rake db:reset db:seed` you're telling Rake to run `db:reset` and then run `db:seed`. If you're *just* running `rake db:reset` then it shouldn't be seeding the database; are you maybe confusing *migration* with *seeding*?

Comment: I've run this command with `--trace` and below is the result. It seems it runs db:seed
http://pastebin.com/azru5fDn
I like this behaviour!

Comment: I stand corrected — it does seed as well. I'd prefer that be a more explicit action so you can reset and have all of the tables empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for tips comments!

Answer (score 4):

You can try `Rake::Task["db:reset"]`invoke.

rake db:reset is just a rake task you can call to reset the database, using Rake::Task lets you call it from a script.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, although I'll probably try to stick to conventions other suggested.

Comment: in console "rake db:reset"